# AWS-Amplify, How do I redirect to another URL after sign-in in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm using the latest AWS-Amplify's authentication component. It can logged in successfully but after login I need to sent the route to another url which I can't able to achieve, it keeping the same url after logged in. BUT I need to set a custom url where it automatically redirect if a user login successfully.

Note : I'm not using `aws-amplify-angular` package I'm using these packages,

```
 "@aws-amplify/ui-angular": "^2.4.4", 
 "aws-amplify": "^4.3.21",
```

Also I checked this `import {AuthenticatorService} from '@aws-amplify/ui-angular';` service but here I didn't find any response with observable type, I think that's why I don't get any event or something instantly after user login successfully. I need to route imminently after a successful login. So I need an event so that I can do that .

My `main.ts` :

```
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify'
import awsmobile from './aws-exports'
Amplify.configure(awsmobile)
```

`auth.component.html` : [ there is no code in `ts` ]

```
<amplify-authenticator [signUpAttributes]="['email']"></amplify-authenticator>
```

& the routes setup like this,

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    component: AuthComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

I didn't get any good solution with using this packages. Please help with this issue or am I missed something in my configuration .

Comment: I also open a discussion session on GitHub you can also join there https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/discussions/9906

Comment: Hi! I responded to the discussion there on how you would do this latest `@aws-amplify/ui-angular`

Comment: @WilliamLee yes, i got that.

Comment: Who want to check an alternative answer you can check out this github discussion https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/discussions/9906

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't want to use `aws-amplify-angular` package but I need to because there is no good solution out there, without this package I tried to use angular hooks because when change detection runs I can get `authenticated` & `unauthenticated` states from `AuthenticatorService` which came from `import { AuthenticatorService } from '@aws-amplify/ui-angular';`  but using hooks (`AfterContentChecked`, `AfterViewChecked`) it works sometimes,sometimes not & sometimes occurred errors.

[ I did't use both hooks at a time, I tried separately]

So, Finally I need to install `aws-amplify-angular` for using the `AmplifyService`'s & then I do this changes bellow,

```
 constructor(private router: Router, private amplifyService: AmplifyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.amplifyService.authStateChange$.subscribe(({state, user}) => {
      if (state === 'signedIn') {
        this.router.navigate(['/home'])
      }
    })
  }
```

Don't forget to add `AmplifyService` to put in providers array in `app.module.ts`.

Comment: An alternative answer you will get here, checkout this https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/discussions/9906

Answer (score 2):

In the `AuthenticatorService` import of the latest version of `@aws-amplify/ui-angular`, you can subscribe and listen for `authStatus` which is authenticated, deauthenticated and configured, if you listen from `ngOnInit` or from the `constructor` you can wait for the necessary status to do redirection.

It also works for the signOut

```
  constructor(public amplifyService: AuthenticatorService, public router: Router) {
    this.amplifyService = amplifyService;
    amplifyService.subscribe((data: any) => {
      if (data.authStatus === "authenticated") {
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      };
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
```

to make signOut you just have to use this function in your navbar

```
  logOut() {
    this.amplifyService.signOut()
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
```

This way you can maintain the latest version of aws-amplify packages and not get errors or failures from compiling outdated packages or packages that conflict with other aws packages.

Comment: That looks smart @dprieto, I might shift to this solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Hub } from 'aws-amplify';

ngOnInit() {
  // Used for listening to login events
  Hub.listen('auth', ({ payload: { event, data } }) => {
    if (event === 'signIn') {
      const { signInUserSession = {} } = data;
      const { accessToken = {} } = signInUserSession;
      const { jwtToken, payload = {} } = accessToken;
      const { 'cognito:groups': roles, username, exp } = payload;
      localStorage.setItem('accessToken', jwtToken);
      const payloadToSave = {
        Role: roles[0],
        Username: username,
        exp,
      };
      localStorage.setItem('payload', JSON.stringify(payloadToSave));
      this.zone.run(() => this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']));
    } else {
      console.log('Hide loader');
    }
  });
  //currentAuthenticatedUser: when user comes to login page again
  Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
    .then(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'], { replaceUrl: true });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: seems elegant, thanks for your support. @Abhay